# Resize multiple files and rename them properly

Tags: command-line

I have a command line problem - probably a pretty easy one, but it seems I can't enter the right words into google.

So I want to resize all *.png images in the folder using imagemagick - this would be something like "convert -resize 80%  " and I want "filename" → "small_filename"

So I tried:

```
for f in *.png ; convert -resize 80% "$f" "small_$f" ; done
```

but "syntax error near unexpected token `convert" - I suppose you can't just import imagemagick commands into the bash ?

I would be delighted if you could help.

Comment: You are missing a `do` keyword: `for f in *.png; do convert ...`

Comment: @steeldriver Shouldn't this be an answer, not a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed `do` after `for ...` string. Here is a slightly modified script, but your version will work also if you add `do` missing in there.

```bsh
for f in *.png
  do
  echo "Converting $f."
  convert "$f" -resize 80% "${f/.png/-80%.png}"
done
```

A name changing here works as follows: for every `$f` as a text string find its `.png` part and change it for `-80%.png`

Comment: Your answer has been flagged low quality. Could you please improve it by adding some information on *why* this works?

Comment: @kraxor yes, sure, I put an explanation to the answer.