# Select multiple files as input and output

Tags: command-line, xubuntu

I am new at linux.
I am using opus audio codec and to convert a wav file into opus file I am using below command.

```
$ opusenc --bitrate 64 male_angry_testing.wav male_angry_testing_opus.opus
```

Here `male_angry_testing.wav` and `male_angry_testing_opus.opus` are input and output file.
But I want to convert multiple file like this but not individually. Is there any looping method which I can use for this conversion ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize multiple files and rename them properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510543/resize-multiple-files-and-rename-them-properly)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting. I am trying that way. @FedonKadifeli

Comment: @AdityaParikh If my answer dosen't work,  tell me the output of it,  I am not a expert pro at bash and loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```bsh
for i in *.wav;
  do name=$(echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1)
  echo "$name"
  opusenc --bitrate 64 "$i" "${name}.opus"
done
```

Or (using shell parameter expansion to avoid the external `cut` command):

```bsh
for i in *.wav; do 
  opusenc --bitrate 64 "$i" "${i%.wav}.opus"
done
```

**Thanks @user3140225 for helping with the formatting.**

Comment: Hi, @William - I tried to implement the way you suggested, but I am getting an errorSes01F_impro01_F001
opusenc: invalid option -- 'i'
Usage: opusenc [options] input_file output_file.opus

Encode audio using Opus.
The input format can be Wave, AIFF, FLAC, Ogg/FLAC, or raw PCM.

input_file can be:
  filename.wav      file
  -                 stdin

output_file can be:
  filename.opus     compressed file
  -                 stdout

General options:
 -h, --help         Show this help
........

Comment: Oh god, sorry typo- remove the -i  (And,  I should add - use the command opusenc as you would on 1 single file, I am not very familiar with the program opusenc but) Hope it works

Comment: yes,,,it works. Thanks a lot... LEGEND. :-P